# Spring security permitAll requires Authorization header

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an application that has two REST endpoints:

- GET /api/products (not secure)
- POST /api/products (secure)

For the first endpoint i don't want to send the "Authorization" header. For this, I configure the following xml:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/products" method="GET" access="permitAll"/>
```

And for the second endpoint I do want to send the "Authorization" header. So, I configure this xml:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/products" method="POST" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
```

For my surprise GET /api/products is requiring an "Authorization" header and it returns 401. And POST /api/products works very nice. I just send an "Authorization" header with a valid value and everything goes well.

I realize that using `<security:intercept-url>` with access="permitAll" does not disable the need of "Authorization" header, is that correct ? If so, what kind of configuration I can setup for achieve my goal ?

I am using Spring Security 4

Comment: Have you tried simply comment `<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/products" method="GET" access="permitAll"/>` (or delete) from configuration? :)

Answer (score 0):

You should simply remove `<security:intercept-url pattern="/api/products" method="GET" access="permitAll"/>` and do not specify any security configuration for `/api/products` `GET` resources.